# Can't link XlsxReaderWriter in Xcode 10

Tags: ios10, xlsx

I need to create an iOS app that reads and writes Excel .xlsx formatted files. Using XlsxReaderWriter I have tried countless times to link following instructions in the README.md file, but have never succeeded. It says that older systems can use libz.dylib instead of libz.tbd, but I can only find libz.tbd and newer versions up to libz.1.2.8.tbd when compiling on Xcode 10. Perhaps there are issues with newer versions of libz that are undocumented.

I've run out of ways to link, install, and run an app with XlsxReaderWriter and wonder if anyone could share a simple app in Objective-C that would show what a successful installation looks like. Endless thanks will follow. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I'm completely SOL so I've had to stop development on this project for now. Bummer.

Comment: That sucks. Currently trying to link this framework without any luck. It doesn’t work on pods either. It’s completely broken :/